# what is the difference between [[],[]] and [[]] * 2

Tags: python

```
t0 = [[]] * 2                                                                   
t1 = [[], []]                                                                   

t0[0].append('hello')                                                           
print t0                                                                        

t1[0].append('hello')                                                           
print t1
```

The result is

```
[['hello'], ['hello']]
[['hello'], []]
```

But I can't tell their difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[[]] * 2
```

makes a [shallow copy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) Equivalent to:

```
x = []
t0 = [x, x]
```

However

```
t1 = [[], []]
```

Uses two separate empty list literals, they are completely different so mutating one obviously doesn't mutate the other

Comment: If I want to declare a list with n empty list, how could I do ?

Comment: @user1807991 `items = [[] for i in range(N)]` notice how this just uses the empty list literal in a list comprehension to make sure they are seperate

Answer (score 10):

When you do `[[]] * 2`, it gives you a list containing two of *the same list*, rather than two lists. It is like doing:

```
a = []
b = [a, a]
```

The usual way to make a list containing several *different* empty lists (or other mutable objects) is to do this:

```
t1 = [[] for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: Even better might be to point out mutable, vs immutable objects. Such as showing the difference in behaviour with tuples and lists here?